Laravel queue error leads to HTTP request duplication
I have a queue, and a job, that makes a HTTP request to a external service via API. It sometimes is taking a long time to respond, and then it throws an error:

But the external service keeps running and makes changes to DB. And when you restart queue, this job dispatches again, so server dows the same thing twice.
If it is HTTP request's timeout's fault, why does queue stops with an error, and why external service still continues to execute request.
Job class:
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Promocode;
use App\Models\SpentPromocode;
use App\Models\Ticket;
use App\Services\SmsServices;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

class ProcessApplyReserve implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected array $data1C;

    public $tries = 14400;
    /**
     * @var mixed|null
     */
    protected mixed $sum;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct(array $data, $sum = null)
    {
        $this->data1C = $data;
        $this->sum  = $sum;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        try {
            $response = Http::timeout(60)->withBasicAuth(config('services.1s.login'),config('services.1s.password'))->post(config('services.1s.url'), $this->data1C);
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            //Some logs
            $this->release($this->attempts()==1?0:60);
            return;
        }
        if($response->failed()){
            //Some logs
            $this->release($this->attempts()==1?0:60);
            return;
        }
        }
    }
}


just bc you stopped waiting for a response does not mean the server you posted to stopped processing
